# Can I unpack variables in order to check their membership in another list?

Tags: python, variables, membership, iterable-unpacking

I would like to know if I have a list of integers, then can I unpack them to check if they are present in another list or must I do it manually? I know there are built in functions like any() and all() but I am wondering if we can unpack variables during a membership test.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
list2 = [5,3,2,]
if (*list1) in list2:
    print("it works")
```

Comment: That is not valid python sintax, you can try it. Stick to `all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that needs arguments from a collection data type accepts unpacking of the collection. You can check membership in this function by comparing the unpacked args against items in another collection. Below is a custom function that accepts unpacking of `list1` and compares items in this list against another list `list2`.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
list2 = [5,3,2]

def intersection(*args, list2):
    for i in args:
        if i in list2:
            print(i)

intersection(*list1, list2=list2)
#Output:
2
3
5
```

You can also use built-in `set` operations like `intersection` to achieve similar results:

```
set(list1).intersection(list2)
#Ouptut:
{2, 3, 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even you have duplicates in the list, you can use `set`:

```py
if set(list2).issubset(list1):
    print("it works")
```

As it will simply check if all items from `list2` exist in `list1`, so duplicates will always exist if their first instance exists.

Regarding your updated question, no you cannot use this syntax in python. Packing/unpacking in function arguments

Comment: What if I want to check if any of the items in list2 are present in list1, must I stick to any()? The main concern is the huge resulting overhead, unless u have any other suggestions

Comment: You can use sets even then, using `if len(set(list2).intersection(list1)) > 0`, or if you simply want to check if one exists, you can use a loop that iterates `list2` and checks `if item in list1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension list

```
If len([x1 if x1 in l2 for x1 in l1])!=0:
  Print('not a great solution with big lists')
```

Comment: I get your idea but the correct version is [x1 for x1 in list1 if x1 in list2]